# Locale and Strings in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator, steam-web-api

I'm currently building a Chrome extension (using yeoman as the starting point) and I've added some packages via npm, one of them being [steam-market-pricing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/steam-market-pricing).

I'm looking to use the language files that were generated by the [generator-chrome-extension](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-chrome-extension) package from yeoman to keep all translations and common phrases in one file (thinking about the future here).

Here's the **language file** code that is used:

```
"steamMarketPrice": {
"message": "Operation Phoenix Weapon Case",
"description": "Name of the item to be fetched from the Steam market"
}
```

To use the language file string, I would use:

```
__MSG_steamMarketPrice__
```

This would then be replaced with whatever it's tied to in the file.

Here's the **steam-market-pricing** code I'm trying to use in my extension:

```
var market = require('steam-market-pricing');
market.getItemPrice(730, 'Operation Phoenix Weapon Case', function(err, data) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

This code will get some information from the Steam marketplace about a certain item in JSON format. My question is, how would I go about using the language file to keep the item search contained within that file?

I've tried replacing the actual name of the item in the **steam-market-pricing** code with the language string above but it doesn't get replaced when it gets baked as a URL which breaks the search. What am I doing wrong?

Sorry if it sounds confusing, if you need any more information I'll be glad to provide it, thanks.

Comment: The term "locale" seems to be used here as a synonym for "language", which it should not be.

Comment: I've changed my question slightly, I wrote this very early this morning and reading it back I understand what you mean, thanks for the heads up.